PBIRS Subscription gives network packet error on random reports
Some reports on PBIRS server regularly give this error.
Other reports which run at almost same time of the day run perfectly.
I've already tried to rename the subscription, change time of the subscription, delete and recreate subscription.
Error: ORA-12570: Network Session: Unexpected packet read error

